# How to create JSON array inside JSON array and JSON object in that dynamically NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am new to NodeJS and trying to reformate the JSON array which I get from MySQL database query.

I am having difficulty adding JSON Array into an array with a key such as before `[]` and after `["ABC":[]]` using code.

```
skid.getSkidsForProcessingInvoice = async () => {
  const query = `SELECT s.id as skidId, po.orderNumber,c.companyName FROM skid s INNER JOIN purchase_order po on s.purchaseOrderId = po.id WHERE s.process_status='PROCESSED' AND s.status = 'READY_FOR_INVOICE' AND s.close_status='Closed' ORDER By s.customerId,s.barCode`;
  return await db.runQuery(query);
};

const skids = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await skidTask.getSkidsForProcessingInvoice()));
let rows = [];

skids.forEach(element => {
  if (!rows[element.companyName]) {
    // rows.push(element.companyName);
    rows[element.companyName] = [];
  }
  rows[element.companyName].push(element);
});
```

skids:

```
 [{
    "skidId": 99,
    "orderNumber": "iuryuouo",
    "companyName": "ABC",
  
}, {
    "skidId": 100,
    "orderNumber": "iuryuouo",
    "companyName": "ABC",
    
}, {
    "skidId": 101,
    "orderNumber": "etoiro",
    "companyName": "XYZ",
}]
```

However, I am getting `["ABC", "XYZ"]` as rows.

How can I form the rows as

```
[
  "ABC":[
      {
        "skidId": 99,
        "orderNumber": "iuryuouo",
        "companyName": "ABC",
      
    }, {
        "skidId": 100,
        "orderNumber": "iuryuouo",
        "companyName": "ABC",
        
    }
 ],
 "XYZ":[
    {
        "skidId": 101,
        "orderNumber": "etoiro",
        "companyName": "XYZ",
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: `["ABC":[]]` is invalid. Arrays don't have keys, only objects do. Do you mean `{"ABC":[]}`? Also what is the point of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`?

Comment: Thanks @str I changed let rows=[] to let rows={} and it worked.

Comment: @str, **JavaScript** arrays are objects and can have properties.  It's the initializer syntax that doesn't exist. `let x=['a','b','c']; x.message = 'hello';`  is valid but `let x = ['a', 'b', 'c', message: 'hello'];` is not.  Furthermore it's specifically **JSON** that doesn't support arrays with properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @str Arrays don't have keys and only object So here is the code that worked for me.

```
const skids = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await skidTask.getSkidsForProcessingInvoice()));
  let data = {}
   skids.forEach(element => {   
        if(!rows[element.companyName]){ 
         rows[element.companyName]=[];
        }
        rows[element.companyName].push(element);
      });
```